# How to delete a git local repo folder in windows 7

Tags: node.js, git, github, npm

I have created git clone in local directory. Then I have run npm and also installed some node packages(gulp etc). But I don’t want now the working directory. So I just did right click mouse and delete, I am not able to delete. I am getting the below error.

> "The source file name(s) are larger than is supported by the file
>   system. Try moving to a location which has shorter path name, or try
>   renaming to shorted name(s) before attempting this operation"

What would be the issue.

Comment: Doesn't sound like a programming problem, sounds more like a basic computer usage problem, something fit for [su]. What operating system are you using?

Comment: I am using Windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows, [this thread](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_vista-files/the-source-file-names-are-larger-than-is-supported/438a20a7-a964-4325-b755-8b5d75ddd15b) shows that it can be:

- a path length issue (the path is too long)
- a process issue (which keeps an handle on one of the files being deleted)

> I found out make a drive mapping about halfway into the folder structure you should be able to delete the latter half of the file heirarcy.
>
> For example if you are getting the error trying to delete:

```
\\NAS.Device.Company.com\a\b\c\d\e\f\g\h\i\j\k\l\m\n\o\p\q\r\s\t\u\v\w\x\y\z
```

> Then map a network drive `Z:` to

```
\\NAS.Device.Company.com\a\b\c\d\e\f\g\h\i\j\k\
```

> This will reduce the file herarchy down to a smaller path.
>   Open explorer and view the `Z:` drive.  It should contain a folder called `L` (in this example).
>
> You should now be able to delete the `L` and its subfolders without an issue, thereby deleting half the folder hierarchy.
>   After that, disconnect the `Z:` drive and try to delete whatever is left normally.
>   Problem solved!